# What does special character @ mean in gvim?

Tags: vim

Register `%` contains the name of the current file, and register `#` contains the name of the alternate file. These registers allow the name of the current or alternate files to be displayed or inserted. The name, or full path, or directory containing the file can be used.

For example, in directory `/abc` the command `vim def/my.txt` would edit file `/abc/def/my.txt`. The following commands could be entered to display the information shown.

```
:echo @%    def/my.txt  directory/name of file
```

I want to know what does `@` mean here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591277/what-do-these-signs-mean-in-vim

Comment: it is not the same meaning as that in my context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@` is a sigil, or special prefix attached to a variable name, that interprets a register like a variable. Other sigils are `$` for environment variables, and `&` for Vim options.

```
:echo f  " prints variable named f
:echo @f " prints contents of register f
:echo $f " prints contents of environment variable f
:echo &fenc " prints the value of :set fileencodings?
```

Instead of `@a`, you could also use `getreg('a')`, which is the corresponding Vimscript function. The `@` is just a convenient shortcut.

You'll find this in the help under `:help expression-syntax` (`expr9`)